# Looking for support

Tags: 7

After a long illness and hospitalization, I have resumed the maintenance of the D7 website of a small patient association. Migration to D10 was partially successful. Article content has been transferred, but photos are still missing. Where can I place a call for someone who can help me specifically? The aim is to be back online quickly and then take the time to keep up with the developments of Drupal of recent years.

Sorry if this is not the place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is a software maintained by a diverse community rather than a company with a support telephone number.

All sources of Drupal support [are categorized](https://www.drupal.org/support).

You may post a request for paid services in [this forum](https://www.drupal.org/forum/services/paid-drupal-services), and stipulate the telephone requirement.